# How to make Vue3 test utils work with teleport

Tags: vuejs3, vue-test-utils, vue-teleport

I have a component that uses teleport to , the test html doesn't seem to be working as expected. I can't find any documentation on this particular use. Here's my test:

```
describe('MetaHead', () => {
  it('dynamic metadata tags contain custom text', () => {

    let title = 'My Page';
    let description = 'Some description about my page';
    // This component uses Vue3's teleport to tag <head>
    // we must modify wrapper to contain such tag
    document.body.innerHTML = `
      <head>
        <div id="app"></div>
      </head>
    `

    const wrapper = mount(MetaHead, {
      attachTo: document.getElementById('app'),
      props: { 
        title,
        description
      },
      global:{
        mocks: {
          $route:{fullPath: 'full/path'}
        } 
      }
    })
    expect(wrapper.html()).toContain(title)
    expect(wrapper.html()).toContain(description)
  })
})
```

and the minimal component looks like this:

```
<template>
  <teleport to="head">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <meta property="og:site_name" :content="title">
    <meta name="description" :content="description">
  </teleport>
</template>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Currently the wrapper is getting:  Received string:    "<!--teleport start--><!--teleport end-->"

Comment: I ended up adding a prop to disable teleport using the component tag, rendering a div if it is disabled.

Comment: Similar issue exists when trying to test content of teleport based 3rd party components, such as PrimeVue dialogs.

Answer (score 3):

the problem here is `wrapper.html()` only returns HTML in your component -  since you are teleporting *outside* your component, that markup won't show up when you call `wrapper.html()`.

You have a few options. One would be making an assertion against `document.body.outerHTML`. Another would be using a neat trick with `findComponent`, I wrote about it [here](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/teleport.html) and posted a video about it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhYtFWDgJmY).

Another thing you could try that I just thought of (but have not tested) would be:

```
mount({
  template: `
    <div id="app" />
    <MetaHead />
  `,
  components: { MetaHead }
})
```

I don't know if that will work, but worth a try.

Comment: The link to your article is 404, any chance you can fix?

Comment: Sorry about the slow reply. I've added a new, working link.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is, you can get element of your destination of teleport in your test.

From your case, you can just get element with id 'app', and get the innerHtml

e.g:

```
it('dynamic metadata tags contain custom text', () => {

let title = 'My Page';
let description = 'Some description about my page';
// This component uses Vue3's teleport to tag <head>
// we must modify wrapper to contain such tag
document.body.innerHTML = `
  <head>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </head>
`

const wrapper = mount(MetaHead, {
  attachTo: document.getElementById('app'),
  props: { 
    title,
    description
  },
  global:{
    mocks: {
      $route:{fullPath: 'full/path'}
    } 
  }
})
expect(document.getElementById('app')?.innerHTML).toContain(title)
expect(document.getElementById('app')?.innerHTML).toContain(description)
})
```